# how to speed up the run of a unity project?

Tags: c#, python, unity-game-engine

Hello i am making a flight simulation with an autopilot so i created the simulation in unity and the autopilot in python but now if i want to train the model i need to wait for 50 hrs for the training process in one iteration and all of that is due to unity rendering the scene ("the actual time needed for the plane to get from say (500,500,500) to (700,500,350) so i need to speed up the game.

i tried only running the code but i didn't know how to do that and if it will work because of the fixed update.

**all i want is to know a way for speeding up the unity scene.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a different [`Time.timeScale`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-timeScale.html) by script:

```
Time.timeScale = 10;
```

makes your game run 10 times **faster** than realtime.

> If you lower `timeScale` it is recommended to also lower [`Time.fixedDeltaTime`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-fixedDeltaTime.html) by the same amount.

so from the example simply after the first line also add

```
Time.fixedDeltaTime = 0.02f * Time.timeScale;
```

---

I would simply do that in a component like

```
public class TimeScaler : MonoBehaviour
{
    // adjust in Inspector
    public float initialTimeScale = 1.0f;

    private void Start()
    {
        SetTimeScale(initialTimeScale);
    }

    // Can now also be called rom other scripts
    public void SetTimeScale(float scale)
    {
        Time.timeScale = scale;
        Time.fixedDeltaTime = 0.02f * Time.timeScale;
    }
}
```

This way you could simply adjust the scale via the Inspector or also re-use the component later from other scripts if you e.g. want to change the timeScale forth and back at certain moments.